# New to servers, just recieved an intransa va expandr

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge, sas

Intransa VA-EXPANDR 12 2 TB Disk array question.

I received this 12 disk array along with a dell poweredge 2850. I would like to set up a RAID but i'm having trouble understanding how to hook up to the 12 disk array. It has an output port on the back that takes a SAS SFF-8088 cable but the poweredge does not have a SAS port. The cable came with it is a SFF-8088 to SFF-8470 SAS cable.

Do i directly hook up the disk array to the poweredge? In that case would it be a raid controller with a SFF-8470 port that i would need to buy for the poweredge or a differn't type of card.

I've been looking this up for hours now, im lost. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i directly hook up the disk array to the poweredge?

Yes

> In that case would it be a raid controller with a SFF-8470 port that i
>   would need to buy for the poweredge.

Yes